# How to show full world map in view react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sckuh.png)
I want to display full world map in view react native

Comment: cant you achieve it with react native maps https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/HEAD/docs/mapview.md

Comment: I already used react native map library but i want see whole map as above image link see full work map in given view

Comment: did you found any solution? i also want full world map

Comment: No still not found any solution @KrutikaChotara

Comment: @KrutikaChotara if you find any solution then tell me

Comment: @Ashish  you can pass litemode=true in map. But it is working only on android

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: got any solution for this full world map @Ashish

Comment: Has anyone found solution for this issue @nrion

Answer (score 0):

In map view we can achieve this goal by mapView prop initial region

```
initialRegion=
    {{
        latitude: 0, // This the position data
        longitude: 0, // This is also position data
        latitudeDelta: 200,
        longitudeDelta: 1,
    }}
```

Now to change the Zoom view of the map you should have any location latitude and longitude data, then to zoom in or zoom out view you can alter the values of latitudeDelta and  longitudeDelta with that you have to match the height & width of the screen too.

Here have managed the view for world map and added the expo working link  & code below, so you can check that it might help you.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
export default function App() {
return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
  <MapView initialRegion={{
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        latitudeDelta: 200,
        longitudeDelta: 1,
  }}
    style={styles.map} />
  </View>
  );
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: ‘white’,
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
},
map: {
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  height: 500,
  },
 });
```

https://snack.expo.dev/P-E7jWAx4